# Writing a wrapper for different dependency injection containers in .net core

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, .net-core, wrapper

I wanted to write a **wrapper** around **dependency injection** containers in my **.net core** project, so that whenever I need to inject something in my application, I can use my own injector which is actually using third-party containers like *Autofac* and *SimpleInjection* for injection. This way I can **change my injector without ever changing my code**.

I've written an **interface** for this purpose which has some needed methods:

```
  interface IDependencyBuilder
    {
        void CreateContainer();

        IContainer Build();

        void RegisterModule<T>() where T : Module, new();

    }
```

And I've implemented it for the **Autofac** like this:

```
public class AutofacContainerBuilder : IDependencyBuilder
    {
        private readonly ContainerBuilder _containerBuilder;

        public AutofacContainerBuilder()
        {
            _containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        }
        public void CreateContainer()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public IContainer Build()
        {
            return _containerBuilder.Build();
        }

        public void RegisterModule<T>() where T : Autofac.Module,new()
        {
            _containerBuilder.RegisterModule<T>();
        }
    }
```

I think something is wrong with this kind of implementation and writing wrapper.

**1**.**Signatures and Input/Output models**: I don't exactly know what functions with what signatures should be written in the wrapper.

**2**. **Implementations for Different Third Parties**: For creating a container I've to have it in the constructor and the create container method cannot be implemented.

I expect to handle the dependency injection in my modular application with my wrapper.

What is the correct way of doing this for a modular web application?

Comment: You have a leaky abstraction that also appears to be tightly coupled to implementation concerns. Try using Generics.

Comment: It appears you are trying to recreate something similar to [IServiceProviderFactory<TContainerBuilder> Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iserviceproviderfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that `Provides an extension point for creating a container specific builder and an IServiceProvider.`. You could consider following a similar design.